# How can i set a background color to a value in PowerBI using DAX?

Tags: azure, powerbi, dax, background-color

I have made a formule in PowerBI using DAX. But i wanna set a background color to every value i have tried allot of things but i couldn't find anything. I My code is as following.

```
var Periods = SWITCH(TRUE(), Live <=maxdate, "Live", Accept <= maxdate, "Accept", Recieved < maxdate, "Recieved", Send < maxdate, "MessageSend",Decline < maxdate, "Request Declined")
```

For example i wanna add the color Red to Request declined. I wanna do this in my switch statement. How can i do this the best way ?

Comment: It's called [conditional formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You would need a column or measure which defines the color based on your requirement / condition. This populate the color value based on the condition.

```
BGColor = VAR col = SELECTEDVALUE(Projects[Periods])
    RETURN IF(col = "Request Declined", "#40E0D0", "#FFA07A")
```

Select the visual in which you would like to apply the formatting

Choose the field which needs the background color.

[image]

In the subsequent window, choose the Format by **Field value**, select the **based on field**

[image]

Select the newly created column/measure.

You could refer to this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-conditional-table-formatting#color-based-on-a-calculation) to get a better picture.

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work